# WordPress NOT notifying of new update in dashboard

Tags: updates, automation

My website is currently running version 4.0.1.

I never even noticed it was an old version until a ran a sucuri website scan which identified that I was running an out-of-date version of software.

I went into Dashboard -> Updates but I get nothing - no updates (even after clicking "check again"

I am running W3 Total cache and I emptied all the caches (just in case) and this didn't change anything.
I am using The7 theme.

Is there any way to trace what is being sent and received during the update check?

Comment: Did you disable update check from `wp-config.php`, plugin or theme function?

Comment: Not on purpose.  But even so, when I manually initiate "Check now" would that not force a check anyway?

Comment: If you have disable HTTP requests (with wp-config.php, plugin or theme function) then you probably cannot.

Comment: Http requests have not been disabled.